# Asking support status of Node.js for UNIX

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask the following on the main site?:

I know the Node.js is available via **freeBSD** `pkg` or probably with `ports`. I have actually had an installation from the `pkg` recently.
However, on Nodejs.org ther is no version for any UNIX or freeBSD. Does that mean it is not officially supported by Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possible questions here:

1. Does node.js officially support BSD? This is essentially a question about a programming framework and whether or not the developers of the framework "officially" support operating system X. I would recommend asking on Stack Overflow instead.
2. How can I get node.js to work on BSD? That is fine for Unix & Linux since you're asking how to do X on a *nix machine.